# NVD3: Setting the x & y axis values to Line chart for intervals

Tags: nvd3.js

3 library for graph generation & i am facing problems while setting the X & Y axis for the intervals based upon values. I want to know whether NVD3's java script has inbuilt capabilities to adjust the X axis intervals based upon the number on records inside the data?

I am generating the graph & it possibly sets the y axis's first value to the lowest value of the sample data. If i need to start the y axis from 0 too then how should it be done?

sample data:

```
var data = [{
           "key": "30 Day",
           "values": [{
               "x": 0,
               "y": 18
           }, {
               "x": 1,
               "y": 24
           }, {
               "x": 2,
               "y": 23
           }, {
               "x": 3,
               "y": 27
           },{
               "x": 4,
               "y": 24
           },{
               "x": 5,
               "y": 31
           },{
               "x": 6,
               "y": 37
           },{
               "x": 7,
               "y": 46
           },{
               "x": 8,
               "y": 32
           },{
               "x": 9,
               "y": 23
           },{
               "x": 10,
               "y": 30
           }]
       }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Several NVD3 charts support xDomain/yDomain options. For example:

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart();
chart.xDomain( [ 0, 10 ] ).yDomain( [ 0, 50 ] );
```